# How to Save Geo fencing of google map and check particular point is inside polygon or not in ionic3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**How to save Geofencing and check whether particular point is inside polygon or not **
I want to save a several polygons inside google map and provide some points to check whether these points are inside polygons or not ? At the run time of google map must have to show all polygons, that i have saved as my locations. If point is outside the polygons  then notify that you are out of Polygons area.